# regex - RxJS 6 migration pipe

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, match, rxjs6

I want to create a regex that match the .map function of RxJS and transforms it into a pipe.

For now I have this regex :

> /.map(([^)]+))/g

That will match :

[Regex result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjmOB.png)

But It doesn't work when I have a map inside a map with : .pipe(map($1))

**Output :**

[Output with pipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjmOB.png)

I need to know if the .map is chained with another operator or is ended with a semicolon.

Comment: please avoid posting images, paste the needed text.

Comment: JS doesn't support regex recursion. Which you need if you have to determine if you have nested map's.

Comment: If you need to get the _inner_ map and it _can't_ be chained, it would be something like `\.map\(([^)]+)\)(?=\s*;)` where it is terminated with a `;` semi-colon.

Comment: yes I know they don't have a (?R) option. But your regex worked fine, and even with that, I have to change all the files by hands because it's too complexe, thanks sln.